# Simple Credit card validation

Tags: beginner, haskell, checksum

I'm a beginner to Haskell (intermediate in web-dev stuff and JavaScript) and I'm not really sure what I could do [better for Homework 1 of CIS194 that I'm taking online](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/hw/01-intro.pdf).

The problem statement is as follows (shortened):

> Validate a credit card number by the following steps:
>
> 1. Double the value of every second digit from the right
> 2. Take the sum of the digits of the new values
> 3. Check whether the sum modulo 10 is 0.
>
> Write the functions `toDigits`, `toDigitsRev` and `doubleEveryOther` for the first task, `sumDigits` for the second, and `validate` for the third.

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits x
    | x <= 0       = []
    | divBy10 < 10 = [divBy10, remainder]
    | otherwise    = toDigits divBy10 ++ [remainder]
    where remainder = x `mod` 10
        divBy10   = x `div` 10

toDigitsRev :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsRev x = reverse (toDigits x)

doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther xs = reverse $ doubleEveryOther' (reverse xs)
    where   doubleEveryOther' []       = []
            doubleEveryOther' (x:[])   = [x]
            doubleEveryOther' (x:y:[]) = [x, y*2]
            doubleEveryOther' (x:y:xs) = [x, y*2] ++ doubleEveryOther' xs

sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumDigits xs = sum $ map sum $ map toDigits xs

validate :: Integer -> Bool
validate x = ((sumDigits (doubleEveryOther (toDigits x))) `mod` 10) == 0
```

Comment: What is your main concern?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Your code contains currently two tasks: credit card validation, as well as the towers of Hanoi. Your question would would be better received if you split it into two with short problem statements.

Comment: I took the curtesy to remove the towers of Hanoi and include a problem statement. Please post a new question for the towers and include a problem statement there.

Comment: Thanks Zeta, I'll try and add a problem statement next time I ask a question.

Comment: As an aside, this is called the Luhn algorithm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, it's great that you've used type signatures. So let's have a look at the contents of your functions.

## Use `divMod` instead of `div` and `mod`

In `toDigits`, you both `div` and `mod` `x` by `10`. However, there's a function that combines them both: `divMod`. With that in mind, we can write

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits x
    | x <= 0       = []
    | divBy10 < 10 = [divBy10, remainder]
    | otherwise    = toDigits divBy10 ++ [remainder]
    where (divBy10, remainder) = x `divMod` 10
```

## Avoid left-recursion on `++`

However, your function is currently non-optimal. If you use `x ++ [y]` repeatedly, you end up with \$\mathcal O(n^2) \$ instead of \$\mathcal O(n) \$, as `++` is \$\mathcal O(n) \$ (where \$n\$ denotes the length of the first list).

It's easier to write `toDigitsRev`:

```
toDigitsRev :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsRev x = case x `divMod` 10 of
                  (0, 0) -> []
                  (0, m) -> [m]
                  (d, m) -> m : toDigitsRev d
```

The `case` is just a matter of preference, you can continue to use your guards. Note that we now use `(:)`, which is alwas \$\mathcal O(1) \$. Our `toDigits` is now only

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits = reverse . toDigitsRev
```

## Use simpler patterns where possible

Your patterns in `doubleEveryOther` are a little bit contrived. If we look closely, we can see that we always return the input, except for the two-element case. Let's reorder the patterns first to see that:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther xs = reverse $ doubleEveryOther' (reverse xs)
    where   doubleEveryOther' (x:y:xs) = [x, y*2] ++ doubleEveryOther' xs
            doubleEveryOther' []       = []
            doubleEveryOther' (x:[])   = [x]
            doubleEveryOther' (x:y:[]) = [x, y*2]
```

Now the first pattern handles **both** `(x:y:xs)` and `(x:y:[])`, so we can get rid of the last pattern:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther xs = reverse $ doubleEveryOther' (reverse xs)
    where   doubleEveryOther' (x:y:xs) = [x, y*2] ++ doubleEveryOther' xs
            doubleEveryOther' []       = []
            doubleEveryOther' (x:[])   = [x]
```

In our empty and single-element pattern we return our input, so we can combine both variants into a single pattern:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther xs = reverse $ doubleEveryOther' (reverse xs)
    where   doubleEveryOther' (x:y:xs) = x : y*2 : doubleEveryOther' xs
            doubleEveryOther' xs       = xs
```

Also, it's common to use short names for workers, so let's call the worker `go`:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther = reverse . go . reverse
    where   go (x:y:xs) = x : y*2 : go xs
            go xs       = xs
```

The point-free definition of `doubleEveryOther` is a matter of preference.

## Other remarks

`sumDigits` and `validate` are fine, although I'd write them as follows

```
sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumDigits  = sum . map (sum . toDigits)

validate :: Integer -> Bool
validate x = checksum == 0
  where
    checksum = sumDigits (doubleEveryOther $ toDigits x) `mod` 10
```

That's only a matter of personal preference, though. The compiler will change `map f $ map g` to `map (f . g)` automatically, so your variant of `sumDigits` didn't traverse the list twice.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll go implement and synthesise these changes now

Comment: I'm kinda just curious tho, with the way that you refactored the pattern matches in doubleEveryOther' , I feel like theres a case for mine being more explicit and readable, whereas the doubleEveryOther' xs = xs doesn't really explain whats going on that well. I dunno

Comment: `go` is `zipWith (*) (cycle [1,2])`.